# Chrome Extension not redirecting on certain URLs

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

New to Chrome Extension development and I'm trying to do something rather simple - read the URL I'm on and redirect if it's during a range of hours. I've basically gotten it to work but for some reason it's only working on the Developer links for Google. Facebook and Reddit aren't redirecting and I'm not sure why.

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Busy Time",
  "description": "Redirect from distractions during active hours",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["popup.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://facebook.com/*",
        "https://reddit.com/*",
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

popup.js:

```
var date = new Date();
var currentHours = date.getHours();

if ((currentHours >= 8 && currentHours <=12) || (currentHours >= 13 && currentHours <=15)) 
{
  window.location.replace("https://google.com")
}
```

I'm not really sure why it works on the developer.chrome.com URL but not Facebook/Reddit so any insight would be great! I'm sure this isn't the most ideal way to do this but it's more for personal use than commercial at this point in time.

Comment: Is the code running at all? Add a `console.log()` call.

Comment: If the domain is `www.reddit.com` it won't match a `reddit.com` URL.

Comment: it was the www missing!

Comment: See also [Chrome address bar no longer shows protocol or www subdomain](https://superuser.com/a/1498561)

Answer (score 0):

Per a user's observation it was missing www from the url. I've gotten it to work now with wildcards:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["popup.js"],
      "matches": [
        "*://*.facebook.com/*",
        "*://*.reddit.com/*"      
      ]
    }
```